# Trying to get data for every 6 months

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running SQL Server and trying to get data for every 6 months.

Here is my query but it is for year, I want it to be every 6 months:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT YEAR(datein) AS 'Year',
    COUNT(*) AS 'Total' 
FROM
    users 
GROUP BY
    YEAR(datein)
```

I want the column value should appear as: `MONTH/YEAR`

Comment: What results do you want?

Comment: Why use `DISTINCT` *and* `GROUP BY` in the same query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `month()` or `quarter()` and some arithmetic.  Here is one way:

```
select YEAR(datein) as Year, FLOOR((MONTH(datein) - 1) / 6) as Year_Part,
       COUNT(*) as Total 
from users 
group by YEAR(datein), FLOOR((MONTH(datein) - 1) / 6);
```

Or, you can put this into two columns:

```
select year(datein) as year,
       sum(case when month(datein) <= 6 then 1 else 0 end) as total_half_1,
       sum(case when month(datein) > 6 then 1 else 0 end) as total_half_2
from users
group by year(datein)
order by year(datein);
```